# php implementation of finding cycle in minimum swaps

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

find out minimum number of adjacent swaps require to make the array sorted.

the approach I use is finding a repeated cycle within my array for example 3->1->4->2 is cycle of 4 so minimum swap of 3 with input of [3,1,4,2,5] to make it sorted [1,2,3,4,5]

I have three arrays, $old contains unsorted array, $arr is sorted, and $bool counts whether the position is visited or not

```
$old = $arr;
quicksort($arr, 0, count($arr) - 1);
$bool = array_fill(0, count($arr), false);
$count = 0;
$circle = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($bool); $i++){
    if ($arr[$i] !== $old[$i]) {
        $circle ++;

        $where = array_search($old[$i], $arr);

        $bool[$i] = true;

        if ($bool[$where]) {
            $count += $circle;
            $circle = 0;
        }
    }
}
return $count;
```

the idea is skipping element that is already in right index,

and mark element that is not, keeping count of cycle (i used $circle), once a right position is already marked, i conclude that a cycle is reached,

but this logic is not behaving what I expected, need some help.

Comment: what is `quicksort` ?

Comment: an quick sort function I wrote to sort the &$arr to ordered array, I could have just used sort(), but I wanted to practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is something like this, however I might be wrong.
I tried to keep it simple with a lot of loops to make it work, and explained the different steps in the code

```
<?php

$minSize = 3;
$arr  = [3,1,2,6,9,3,5,2,6,9,3,5,1,8,4,6,6,9,3,0];
$repeats = [];

//outer loop
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    $currValue = $arr[$i];
    //get all the keys for where the value is the same as $currValue
    //this gives a starting position to test our matching sets
    $matches = array_keys($arr, $currValue);
    //match loop
    for($j = 0; $j < count($matches); $j++) {
        $leftIndex = $currValue; //this needs to be reset for every set
        $matchIndex = $matches[$j];
        //now we do want matches only when the index is different, always it will always match
        if($leftIndex === $matchIndex) {
            continue;
        }

        $subsequentMatch = 0;
        //isset so we don't go out of bounds of our array
        while(isset($arr[$leftIndex], $arr[$matchIndex]) && $arr[$leftIndex] === $arr[$matchIndex]) {
            $subsequentMatch++;
            $leftIndex++;
            $matchIndex++;
        }

        if($subsequentMatch >= $minSize) {
            $repeats[] = array_slice($arr, $currValue, $subsequentMatch) ;
        }
    }
}

print_r($repeats);
```

See an example here : https://3v4l.org/cBWQ5

you could improve on this by doing

for($i = 0; $i < (count($arr) - $minSize ); $i++) {

because if the set is under `$minSize` it will never be added to the repeats

**EDIT: based on comments, OP might be looking for this ?**

```
<?php

$arr  = [3,1,2,6,9,3,5,2,6,9,3,5,1,8,4,6,6,9,3,0];
$swapCount = 0;
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) use (&$swapCount) {
    if($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    $swapCount++;
    return $a <=> $b;
});

echo 'Arr Count: ' . count($arr) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Swaps performed: ' . $swapCount;
```

This is a simple sort, I suppose you could write a usort and count with each different sort mechanism (the list is endless), and then find out the min value of that

list of sorting mechanism off the top of my head

- Insert Sort
- Bubble Sort
- Quick Sort
- Counting Sort
- Comb Sort
- Heap Sort
- Merge Sort
- Shell Sort
- Odd Even Sort

You can google on how to implement these in PHP, there are probably more ways too.

Comment: I am sorry if my post is confusing to understand, what I want is find out minimum number of adjacent swaps require to make it sorted.

Comment: I added a function that counts how many time it swaps 2 values, with usort, but i doubt that is what you are looking for

Comment: unfortunately no, I need to find out minimum number of swaps needed to make it sorted

Comment: bubble sort seems to give minimum number of swaps, however it has complexity of O(n^2), what I am trying to do is O(n log n). In my post I have already written a quick sort (but the number of swaps is much greater than minimum), and tried to compare the differences between sorted and unsorted to find out size of cycles, add them up to get min swaps